# How do I redirect asynchronous output to a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, console.log

I have a Node.js script that reads the contents of a file, does some transformations on its contents, and logs the output:

```
var transformer = require('./transformer'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    file = process.argv[2];

if (!file) {
    throw 'no file specified\n';
}

fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    transformer.transform(data, function (text) {
        console.log(text);
    });
});
```

This works fine:

```
$ node transform.js myfile.txt
```

And this works:

```
$ node transform.js myfile.txt > anotherfile.txt
```

But, when I try to redirect the output to the same file I'm reading from, the file becomes blank:

```
$ node transform.js myfile.txt > myfile.txt
```

Same thing using `tee`:

```
$ node transform.js myfile.txt | tee myfile.txt
```

Curiously, this works:

```
$ node transform.js myfile.txt >> myfile.txt
```

But I don't want to append to the file - I want to overwrite its contents.

I think the problem is, since `fs.readFile` is asynchronous, `console.log` is called asynchronously as well - i.e., it gets chunks of data as opposed to all the data at once. I think I can use `fs.readFileSync` instead, but what's the right way to handle this?

Comment: do you think the file handle was still open when you check the notepad?, if im not mistaken as long as the file handle is open, the data is not literally written onto the file, though during debug steps it could probably said the writing was already done. (coming from c# perspective), also notepads are notoriously unreliable (during ocular checks) due to the fact that you can delete a notepad even if the file itself is open.

Comment: It's nothing to do with nodejs. It's just how the shell works. The traditional way of doing this would be `node transform.js myfile > tmp;mv tmp myfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not actually within Node but in the shell. When you redirect with `>`, the first thing the shell does is open the file for writing, emptying the file. Your program goes to read from that empty file and, in your case, empty input means empty output.

This too will result in an empty file regardless of the initial contents of `myfile.txt`:

```
$ cat myfile.txt > myfile.txt
```

One solution would be to write the file inside the Node script rather than using redirection. You're already specifying and reading the file there, so why not specify an output file in `argv` as well and write to it rather than using shell redirection? Just take care to structure your code so that reading and writing to the same file works.

As @slebetman notes in a comment, another solution is `cat myfile.txt > tmp; mv tmp myfile.txt` (or my preferred: `cat myfile.txt > tmp && mv tmp myfile.txt`).

Comment: The traditional solution in the shell is `cat myfile.txt > tmp; mv tmp myfile.txt`

Comment: Thanks, I've added that as an option to the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

- you're opening the file for read,
- then opening the file for write (emptying it),
- then reading from an empty file.
- transform nothing
- write nothing

What I think you want instead is to:

- open for read
- read and buffer
- transform
- open for write
- write

There's a couple ways to do this:

1) Read the file synchronously.  [Node.js 0.12 supports this](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options).

```
var transformer = require('./transformer'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    file = process.argv[2];

if (!file) {
    throw 'no file specified\n';
}

fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    transformer.transform(data, function (text) {
        console.log(text);
    });
});
```

2) Use "streams"

This is really the best way.  Especially if you're wanting to learn Node.js

The best way I know to learn about streams is from NodeSchool: http://nodeschool.io/#workshoppers  Try the `stream-adventure`.

By the end, you'll **own** these kinds of problems.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm curious why the downvote? Is it because neither of the proposed solutions would actually fix the problem?

Comment: All the solutions here (mine and Trott's) work.  Trott was working in bash, which is good as the simplest-thing-could-possibly-work.  Mine use node's features to solve the problem.  It just depends on what you want to do.  Why the downvote?  Because haters gotta hate :-)